# Why must the value type of map type be the same

Tags: typescript

I hope the value of the map type can be number or string, but typescript reports an error.

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBGICcCGBbANgLhgWSQBwB5oEBLMAcwBoZizyYAfOAVxQCMBTBAPhgF44HAO458ACgDaAKBiyY0uYpgByAIzLKMpbLUatsgLqbFC7SoBMeszFXG5RqQYCUAbiA)

```js
const map: Map<string, string | number> = new Map([
    [
        '1',
        '1',
    ],
    [
        '2',
        1,
    ],
]);

error: No overload matches this call.
```

Comment: const noraml: Map<string, string | number> = new Map<string, string | number>(.....);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Passing the types in the initializer works:

```js
const noraml = new Map<string, string | number>([
    [
        '1',
        '1',
    ],
    [
        '2',
        2,
    ],
]);
```